How to add Changed-By while building with debuild for launchpad?
I decided to fork a package and put it on my PPA on launchpad. But it Keeps getting rejected beacuse sources.changes file dosen't has Changed-By: other package i forked is accepted but Changed-By is still old mainstainer and i tried to search for him with jedit in all files but i didnt find a line making CHanged-By in source code for both packages.
Email from Lanchpad:
Rejected: Unable to find mandatory field 'Changed-By' in the changes file. Further error processing not possible because of a critical previous error. horizon-installer (0.1.0) noble; urgency=medium === If you don't understand why your files were rejected please send an email to launchpad-users@lists.launchpad.net for help (requires membership).

Did you update the changelog (with your name/email) and run debuild -S to generate the .sources.changes file?

Can you share a github link of your repository? Then it would be easier to debug

I updated my answer. Please follow it step by step, and let me know what does not work. If something does not work, edit the question and add the full terminal output. If there is any warning, do NOT proceed to the next step without fixing the warning. Instead, let us know by updating the question.

You are NOT supposed to modify source.changes. What is the output of debuild -S?

Your package lists libdistinst-dev as a dependency, but there is no such package like that. As a result, even if it is correctly uploaded, it will not build. It did not build for me https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/expt/+build/29104230. Please first ensure that you can build it locally, and ensure that the dependencies listed in debian/control are correct

If my answer worked for you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left side.

Prerequisites: You will need to set up PGP keys and SSH keys to build a package and upload them to Launchpad, respectively.

Your debian/changelog was wrongly formatted. I sent a pull request to fix it.

First, increase the version number from something like x.y to x.y-2 in the debian/changelog.

Locally build the package with debuild -S. It will create a sources.changes for you, and the package will be signed by your key.


Finally, upload this sources.changes to launchpad using dput.

I did those steps but my package_source.changes has 'Changed-By:' and Launchpad won't accept it. E-mail i keep getting: Rejected:
Unable to find mandatory field 'Changed-By' in the changes file.
Further error processing not possible because of a critical previous error.
horizon-installer (0.1.0) noble; urgency=medium
===
If you don't understand why your files were rejected please send an email
to launchpad-users@lists.launchpad.net for help (requires membership).

Please write this in the body of the question. Note that you should not manually change Changed-By, that will not work

Then how it dosent generate it or the generated one is wrong for me so how to do it?

here is the repo https://github.com/horizonlinux/installer i tried everything Changed-By just dosent appear in the sources.changes after building it

Well I merged it and still nothing. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1136341951315185845/1287028926559817768/image.png?ex=66f00e97&is=66eebd17&hm=ec0a1152557fda96f8e963bb4106cf180649349724325983485c74fe51317ecb& heres what source.changes looks like

OK I GOT IT TO WORK!!! I copied changelog from the package which builded with changed-by changed package name in it and it worked! I have no idea why your fix didn't work but i got it now. ANd I know i can't edit source.changes because checksums won't match.

Feel free to edit my answer and add any information you find relevant

well about libdistinst its part of distinst which is needed for that installer to work. i will just need to put distinst (original not v2) to my ppa

Ok. Then, you first need to upload distinst and build it in your PPA, and then upload your horizon-installer package
